# example of an algebraic curve on a surface that cannot written by a polynomial in a local coordinate

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, for a given algebraic curve on a surface, we can take a local coordinate system $(x,y)$ on a surface to write the curve by power series(by Weierstrass' theorem).

However, it might not be possible the power series ends in finite terms, so I want to have a example that a curve on a surface that cannot written by polynomials in any local coordinate.

Comment: What do you mean with *written by polynomials* (or power series)? A parametrization using polynomial functions? A set of solutions of a system of polynomial equations?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry for ambiguity. What I mean was the second one. Since a curve is of codimension 1 in a surface, it is given by the zero set of only one polynomial or power series.